# How can I stop ZSH in Window 8 waiting for Sublime to close?

Tags: sublimetext2, zsh

The following code correctly loads Sublime as intended.

However, I do not want the console to wait for Sublime to quit.

.zshrc does not include a waiting argument.

Here is the current alias

```
 alias subl="/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text.exe"
```

I would like zsh shell to NOT wait for sublime to quit

Comment: have you tried running `subl &`?

Comment: Don't check in zsh, but you can run "cmd /c start sublime_text.exe". Also, the question is not related to ConEmu.